# What is the physical quantities in the equations for linear elasitc materials in a frequency study in comsol

Tags: comsol

I am using comsol to model a linear elastic materials and perform a frequency domain study. I try to understand the equations it provided but all symbols are not explained. For example,

[image]

How should or where can I find the documents to explain these symbols?

Comment: If you want to model linear elasticity, a good first step would be to read a book about linear elasticity :-)

Comment: I do read some contents about it. However, I still confuse about the notation it used. For example, I really confuse about the $F_v$ or $\phi$ here. This term only occur when you choose a frequency domain study.